# AT command complete output

Tags: at-command, modem, gprs

I want to know how can I get complete output from AT commands?

I am sending the AT command to *Telit UC864-G* via hub and the command looks like following:

```
echo "*AT COMMAND*" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

For example when I issue:

```
echo "AT+CGQREQ=?" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I should normally get some output like:

```
+CGQREQ: <PDP_Type>,(list of supported <precedence>s), (list of supported <delay>s),(list of supported <reliability>s), (list of supported <peak>s),(list of supported <mean>s)
```

where instead I am only getting **"OK"**.

How to get the full/complete output then?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "?" rather than "/"

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant... mistype

Comment: I will probably don't get any answer after all this time, but is it possible that you was simply reading the answer to some comnand previously issued? What if a command like `AT+CPIN?` is sent?